# LiveCode on a terminal server environment?

Tags: livecode, terminal-server

Does anyone know if Livecode runs on a terminal server environment?
We (training institute) wants to install LiveCode on a terminal server connected with over 400 thin clients.

Chris

Comment: I think this is a question for the mothership (LiveCode). I have very little experience using thin clients. But if the thin client is set up like a virtual desktop or virtual machine, I see no reason it shouldn't work. But again, I guess it depends on your setup so send a question to the support at LiveCode and I'm sure they will come back to you.

Answer (score 0):

don't see why it wouldn't work - I'm running the IDE (and StandAlone executables) via RDP on a daily basis, including on a 2K3-R2 Server (yes, I know ...).
LC installs (in Win) like it should - all user specifics in \user\appdata & \user\documents, program in \program files.

And you can easily try the community version anyways. Have fun!